# VUEJS send passwords in axios to API

Tags: security, vue.js, authentication, passwords, axios

How can I secure this code ? Because on the inspector of network, we can see the newPassword et acutalPassword.

The user write this actual password and this new password for change password, in a vue component (2 input). The button execute an axios request and go on my laravel API with post parameters (2 passwords).

```
changePassword(){
  axios.put('/api/user/password/change', {
    password: this.password.actual,
    newPassword: this.password.new,
  })
  .then((response) => {

  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);

  });
}
```

},